# Accepting multiple data packets on a single receiver in WeBots

Tags: c, controller, webots

I am trying to program a receiver module on the e-puck robot to receive data packets and their associated signal strengths from multiple emitter modules.

The problem I am facing is that previous data packets (which haven't been read) are lost when new data is received (see bufferSize in https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/receiver#field-summary). This means that when Webots runs the controller for the receiver module, only the data from the latest emitter is stored in the buffer, and all other data (from other emitters) has been lost before the controller even had the chance to read it.

I tried a few different options but none seem to work:

Running the receiver controller asynchronously (by setting the controller's SYNCHRONISATION to FALSE) to run it more frequently and independent from the Webots time steps so that it has a chance to read data from other emitters too. Didn't seem to make any difference.

Scheduling the emitters to send their data one at a time so that receiver can process the information. This works, but it makes the system respond very slowly to dynamic changes. For context, I am trying to interface the receiver with atleast 7 emitters.

I considered having an interrupt service routine when any data has been added to the receiver's buffer, but I couldn't find any relevant documentation on implementing interrupts in Webots controllers.

I tried reducing the time step of the receiver's controller so that it can run more often and lose lesser data, but Webots requires the controller time steps to be integer multiples of the simulation time steps. Which means that the receiver will always run at the same time as the latest emitter - bringing us back to the same problem.

I think to make my simulation work, I will have to either run the receiver 7 times faster (for example) than the emitters in such a way that it reads data from each emitter every time it runs. Or, change the receiver module's buffer settings somehow to not lose data from previous transfers. Any and all advice appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Caveats:

1. I'm *not* familiar with `webots`
2. I'm *slightly* familiar with ROS but far from an expert.
3. My ROS experience (on a commercial robot project) was a "learn ROS as I go along"
4. So a lot of what I'm about to say could be completely ignorant of the mechanisms that ROS *does* provide.

---

When my process "subscribed" to a published stream, based on the "controller" I was given, the controller created a "hidden" thread that looped on `recv` et. al. and saved the latest state from the stream.

My thread could poll the controller's state. But, frequently, it would say "no new data". My loop would look at timestamps and try to calculate the time it should sleep to be woken up just after new data was posted.

This was fraught with issues, similar to yours.

This was done, AFAICT, so that my thread would be "synchronous".

What I wanted was to "be" the thread that fielded all incoming messages. I was looking for a way to get an async callback from the hidden thread on each incoming message. Unfortunately, the project ended before I could figure that out.

But, my feeling was that I would have to modify the controller to provide a callback [*if* there was no standard mechanism to do this--which I didn't have a chance to locate].

Another issue was that the thread/process that my code ran in could subscribe to multiple streams but each one need to poll the controller interface for the given stream.

Each controller had a hidden thread for each stream that just dealt with the data from the given source.

Ideally, what I wanted was a list of the sockets to the streams, so I could wait for them via a `select` or `poll` syscall. That way, I would be woken up as soon as any data arrived.

---

ROS and/or webots *may* provide such a callback mechanism (which you tried to do by setting the controller's SYNCHRONISATION to FALSE).

Hopefully, there *is* such a mechanism within ROS/webots. Otherwise, you may need to hack up the source. Or, just use portions of the APIs to do the boilerplate of managing connections but establish your own controller.

Subsequent to my ROS experience, along came ROS2. The above caveats still apply ;-) I did a cursory look at it. AFAICT, one significant change was to use multicast sockets instead of unicast. So, if a publisher had multiple subscribers, it could send a *single* packet to the multicast group (vs. sending separate packets to a list of the unicast addresses). So, possibly much more efficient.

---

In order to debug this, I used a technique of mine from some prior (non-ROS) projects. I created a ring queue of "event" structs *with* timestamps and thread IDs. These were *not* events in the ROS sense. Just a trace of the program/process/thread and where it was (e.g.):

```
enum evt_type {
    EVENT_FOO_TOPLOOP,
    EVENT_FOO_POST_WAIT,
    // ...
};

void
foo(void)
{

    for (int iter = 1;  ++iter) {
        event_trace(EVENT_FOO_TOPLOOP,iter);
        wait_for_some_ros_event(stream);
        event_trace(EVENT_FOO_POST_WAIT,iter);
    }
}
```

I peppered the source code with these `event_trace` callbacks. The `event_trace` would add a struct to the ring queue of the form:

```
struct trace_event {
    uint64_t evt_timestamp;                     // event timestamp
    enum evt_type evt_type;                     // event type
    uint64_t evt_data;                          // per-event data
    int evt_tid;                                // sequential thread id
};
```

`event_add` had two global ring queue indices (e.g.) `int queue_enq, queue_deq;`

It would use `stdatomic.h` primitives using `atomic_compare_exchange` to advance the enqueue/dequeue indices (i.e. semi-lockless).

The intent was to have a "low overhead" trace mechanism with little to no spinning/wait.

When the program detected an anomaly (or received a `SIGINT`, etc.) it would call a dump function and the contents of the ring queue was dumped to a file. The dump file was different for each agent/process, (e.g.) `sprintf(file,"event_dump.%d",getpid())`